# My C function recurses over system directories and segfaults over large inputs. How can I fix this?

Tags: c, recursion, segmentation-fault, stack-overflow, directory-structure

I am trying to code a program that searches through a given directory and all sub-directories and files within it (and the sub-directories and files of the sub-directories and so on) and print outs all files that have a given set of permissions (`int target_perm`).

It works fine on smaller input, but returns `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` when it has to recurse over directories with large quantities of files. Valgrind reveals that this is due to stack overflow.

Is there any way I can fix my function so it can work with arbitrarily large directories?

```
void recurse_dir(struct stat *sb, struct dirent *de, DIR *dr, int target_perm, char* curr_path) {
    if ((strcmp(".", de->d_name) != 0) && (strcmp("..", de->d_name) != 0)) {

        char full_file_name[strlen(curr_path) + strlen(de->d_name)+1];
        strcpy(full_file_name, curr_path);
        strcpy(full_file_name + strlen(curr_path), de->d_name);
        full_file_name[strlen(curr_path) + strlen(de->d_name)] = '\0';

        if (stat(full_file_name, sb) < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: Cannot stat '%s'. %s\n", full_file_name, strerror(errno));
        } else {
            char* curr_perm_str = permission_string(sb);
            int curr_perm = permission_string_to_bin(curr_perm_str);
            free(curr_perm_str);

            if ((curr_perm == target_perm )) {
                printf("%s\n", full_file_name);
            }

            if (S_ISDIR(sb->st_mode)) {
                DIR *dp;
                struct dirent *dent;
                struct stat b;
                dp = opendir(full_file_name);

                char new_path[PATH_MAX];
                strcpy(new_path, full_file_name);
                new_path[strlen(full_file_name)] ='/';
                new_path[strlen(full_file_name)+1] ='\0';

                if (dp != NULL) {
                    if ((dent = readdir(dp)) != NULL) {
                        recurse_dir(&b, dent, dp, target_perm, new_path);
                    }
                    closedir(dp);               
                } else {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Cannot open directory '%s'. %s.\n", de->d_name, strerror(errno));
                }
            }           
        }
    }

    if ((de = readdir(dr)) != NULL) {
        recurse_dir(sb, de, dr, target_perm, curr_path);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use recursion?  You could use the standard library function `nftw` instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: (Or, of course, you could just use `find(1)` instead of writing your own program... but I suppose you're doing it for the practice.)

Comment: Yeah exactly. I'm trying to do this for practice and somewhat from scratch.

Comment: You're actually using recursion in two ways here: once to get down to a sub-directory (in the `S_ISDIR` branch) but also to handle every file in the directory.  The first one is somewhat reasonable but the second one is not.  It'd be better just to loop over all the directory entries and only recurse for those which are directories.

Comment: What exactly is it that makes the second recursion attempt unreasonable?

Comment: In the first case, the recursion depth of your function matches the depth of the directory tree; in the second, it is the number of entries in a directory.  (Actually, worst case, it can be the *sum* of all the entries in a directory and all its parents.)  Real-life systems don't often contain extremely *deep* directory hierarchies beyond maybe a few dozen levels, but they do often contain very *large* directories with many thousands of entries.

Comment: Moreover, your function is fairly greedy of stack space (e.g. the local array of size `PATH_MAX`, typically about 4K).  A modern Unix system will usually give your program a few megabytes of stack space, so a few dozen levels of recursion is going to be fine, but a few thousand is not.

Comment: Another point is that recursion is most appropriate when each level of the recursion is keeping important data in its local state.  When recursing by depth, that's the case: at each level, you need to know where in the directory you are, so you can continue when you pop back to that level.  But for your second case, you're doing tail recursion: the caller is not going to do anything further after the recursive call returns, so its local data will never be used again and that stack space is wasted in the meantime.

Comment: Indeed, if you compile with optimizations, there's a chance your compiler will replace the tail recursion with a jump, effectively making it a loop instead of a recursive call, and making your stack overflow go away.  But it isn't good to rely on that behavior; better to redesign the function.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! Thank you so much for taking the time to type out these replies.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is not actually the recursion, although I've addressed that particular problem below. The problem is that your directory hierarchy probably includes symbolic links which make some directories aliases for one of their parents. An example from a Ubuntu install:

```
$ ls -ld /usr/bin/X11
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1 Jan 25  2018 /usr/bin/X11 -> .

$ # Just for clarity:
$ readlink -f /usr/bin/X11
usr/bin
```

So once you encounter `/usr/bin/X11`, you enter into an infinite loop. This will rapidly exhaust the stack, but getting rid of recursion won't fix the problem, since the infinite loop is still an infinite loop.

What you need to do is either:

- Avoid following symlinks, or
- (better) Avoid following symlinks which resolve to directories, or
- Keep track of all the directories you've encountered during the recursive scan, and check to make sure that any new directory hasn't already been examined.

The first two solutions are easier (you just need to check the filetype field in the `struct stat`) but they will fail to list some files you may be interested in (for example, when a symlink resolves to a directory outside of the directory structure you're examining.)

Once you fix the above problem, you might want to consider these suggestions:

1. In recursive functions, it's always a good idea to reduce the size of a stack frame to the minimum possible. The maximum recursion depth during a directory walk shouldn't be more than the maximum number of path segments in a filename (but see point 3 below), which shouldn't be too big a number. (On my system, the maximum depth of a file in the `/usr` hierarchy is 16, for example.) But the amount of stack used is the product of the size of the stack frame and the maximum recursion depth, so if your stack frames are large, then you'll have less recursion capacity.
2. In pursuit of the above goal, you should avoid the use of local arrays. For example, the declaration

   ```
   char new_path[PATH_MAX];
   ```

   adds `PATH_MAX` bytes to every stack frame (on my system, that's 4k). And that's in addition to the VLA `full_file_name`. For what it's worth, I compiled your function on a 64-bit Linux system, and found that the stack frame size is 4,280 bytes plus the size of the VLA (rounded to a multiple of 16 for alignment). That's probably not going to use more than 150Kb of stack, assuming a reasonable file hierarchy, which is within the limits. But that could increase significantly if your system has a larger value of `PATH_MAX` (which, in any case, cannot be relied on to be the maximum size of a filepath).

   Good style dictates using dynamically-allocated memory for variables like these ones. But an even better approach would be to avoid using so many different buffers.
3. Parenthetically, you also need to be aware of the cost of `strlen`. In order to compute the length of a string, the `strlen` function needs to scan all its bytes looking for the NUL terminator. C strings, unlike string objects in higher-level languages, do not contain any indication of their length. So when you do this:

   ```
   char full_file_name[strlen(curr_path) + strlen(de->d_name)+1];
   strcpy(full_file_name, curr_path);
   strcpy(full_file_name + strlen(curr_path), de->d_name);
   full_file_name[strlen(curr_path) + strlen(de->d_name)] = '\0';
   ```

   you end up scanning `curr_path` three times, and `de->d_name` twice, even though the lengths of these strings will not change. Rather than doing that, you should save the lengths in local variables so that they can be reused.

   Alternatively, you could find a different way to concatenate the strings. One simple possibility which also dynamically allocates the memory, is:

   ```
   char* full_file_name;
   asprintf(&full_file_name, "%s%s", curr_path, de->d_name);
   ```

   - **Note:** You should check the return value of `asprintf`, both to verify that there was not a memory allocation problem, and also to save the length of `full_file_name` in case you need it later. `asprintf` is available on Linux and BSD derivatives, including OS X. But it's easy to implement using the Posix-standard `snprintf` and there are short, freely-reusable implementations available.)
   - You could use `asprintf` to compute `new_path`, as well, again removing the stack allocation of a possibly large array (and avoiding the buffer overflow if `PATH_MAX` is not big enough to contain the new filepath, which is definitely possible):

     ```
     char* newpath;
     asprintf("%s/", full_file_path);
     ```

     But that's kind of silly. You're copying an entire filepath just in order to add a single character at the end. Better would be to leave space for the slash when you create `full_file_path` in the first place, and fill it in when you need it:

     ```
     char* full_file_name;
     int full_file_name_len = asprintf(&full_file_name, "%s%s\0",
                                          curr_path, de->d_name);
     if (full_file_name_len < 0) { /* handle error */ }
     --full_file_name_len; /* Bytes written includes the \0 in the format */

     /* Much later, instead of creating new_path: */

     if (dp != NULL) {
         full_file_name[full_file_name_len - 1] = '/';

         if ((dent = readdir(dp)) != NULL) {
             recurse_dir(&b, dent, dp, target_perm, full_file_name);
         }

         full_file_name[full_file_name_len - 1] = '\0';

         closedir(dp);               
     }
     ```

     There are other ways to do this. In fact, you really only need a single filepath buffer which you could pass down through the recursion. The recursion only appends to the filepath, so it's only necessary to restore the NUL byte at the end of every recursive call. However, in production code you would not want a fixed-length buffer, which might turn out to be too small, so you would need to implement some kind of reallocation strategy.
4. While I was trying to figure out the actual stack frame size for your function, which required compiling it, I ran into this code which relies on some undeclared functions:

   ```
       char* curr_perm_str = permission_string(sb);
       int curr_perm = permission_string_to_bin(curr_perm_str);
       free(curr_perm_str);
   ```

   Making a guess about what these two functions do, I think you could safely replace the above with

   ```
       int curr_perm = sb->st_mode & (S_IRWXU|S_IRWXG|S_IRWXO);
   ```

   Or perhaps

   ```
       int curr_perm = sb->st_mode
                       & (S_ISUID|S_ISGID|S_ISVTX|S_IRWXU|S_IRWXG|S_IRWXO);
   ```

   if you want to include the setuid and sticky bits.